# Javascript: Errors arent being displayed on event listeners

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

I have a problem that is driving me crazy. I have two event listeners that appear to be identical. The are being called with the same scope but at different times. I have been using chromes debugger tool to step through them. The first one will throw an error

`TypeError: Object 1 has no method 'get'`

But the second example simple stops executing

```
el.on("change:one", function() {
  debugger;
  a = 1;
  a.get();
});

el.on("change:two", function() {
  debugger;
  a = 1;
  a.get();
});
```

I understand that simple asking why is this happening probably needs a detailed explanation of all the libraries being used etc, so my question is:

Is it possible to not display errors thrown by javascript, and how would I be able to detect whether something is overriding the error reporting functionality

NOTE: In both examples I have determined that `window.onerror` is `null`

Comment: To throw a spanner in the works, I can call el.trigger('change:two') in chromes console and it will display the error...

Comment: Are you _positive_ that the second event handler is being executed? Depending on how the events are triggered, the first error could be halting the execution of whatever functionality is responsible for triggering `change:two`. The fact that you can trigger the events manually and they successfully throw an error supports this.

Comment: 1 is a Number Object .. And it does not have a `get` method.. Try triggering the same for `el.trigger('change:one')`  .. Should be the same

Comment: Following on from @Sushanth-- [MDN Number Object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number) - although I'm fairly certain you already know this.

Comment: @MattStone Yes positive, the browser falls into the debugger mode inside both of the functions.

Comment: @Sushanth-- I know 1 is a Number Object, the point was to force the method to fail. One fails and two doesn't

Comment: That is because the execution stops because of the first error. SO it will never hit the next statement

Comment: I can take the erroring code out of the first one and it gets to the second. My question wasn't to get that example to working, it was about overriding how errors are displayed :)

Answer (score 0):

Backbone invokes event handlers synchronously and doesn't catch handler exceptions. So if you had code that looked like:

```
el.trigger('change:one'); // handler will throw exception
el.trigger('change:two'); // won't execute
```

The `change:two` event will never get triggered, resulting in your `change:two` handler never getting invoked.

Comment: thanks for the answer, I can remove the code that makes change:one work, and change:two does execute, dies but doesnt display errors

Comment: When I removed the exception causing code from the `change:one` handler, I was able to see the error from the `change:two` handler. See this [jsfiddle](http://jsbin.com/ifeviw/1/edit).